# embedded Lua and overloaded C++ operators

Tags: c++, lua

I am embedding Lua in my C++ application.

I have a class Foo which I am exposing to Lua (via tolua++).

Foo overloads some operators as shown below:

```
class Foo
{
   public:
      explicit Foo(const int i);
      bool operator==(const Foo& foo) const;
      bool operator< (const Foo& foo) const;
      int operator-(const Foo& foo) const;

   private:
      int m_ival;
};
```

My question is, in my Lua script, can I then use expressions like that shown below, in my Lua script:

```
f1 = Foo:new(42)
f2 = Foo:new(123)

if f1 < f2 then
   print(f2 -f1)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation tolua++ supports this - see [Binding classes and methods - Overloaded operators](http://www.codenix.com/~tolua/tolua++.html#classes):

> tolua automatically binds the following binary operators:
>
> ```
> operator+   operator-   operator*   operator/ 
> operator<   operator>=  operator==  operator[]
> ```
>
> For the relational operators, toLua also automatically converts a returned 0 value into nil, so false in C becomes false in Lua.
>
> As an example, suppose that in the code above, instead of having:
>
> `Point add (Point& other);              // add points, returning another one`
>
> we had:
>
> `Point operator+ (Point& other);        // add points, returning another one`
>
> In that case, in Lua, we could simply write:
>
> `p3 = p1 + p2`

Answer (score 0):

The desired behavior is possible in Lua. I don't know how to do that with tolua++ (I have never used it), but it could be achieved by defining metamethods for your userdata. For details look at [Relational metamethods](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.2.html). That could give you a clue.